# Unable to update document in cloud firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Facing a strange issue here. I am able to create a new document but when I try to update the same, it doesn't work. This data is being pushed via a Typeform so debugging is challenging in itself, and the error I get on console doesn't help much.

Here's my code:

```
    //Check if user already exists. If she does, update her, otherwise add her
firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(phone).get()
    .then(doc => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
            console.log("Adding new Record");
            var user = {
                phone: phone,
                health_records: [],
                last_interaction_on: last_interaction
            };
            user.health_records.push(health_records);

            firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.phone).set(user);
            res.send("Added new user with health records!")
        }
        else {
            console.log("Updating Records");
            var healthRecords = [];
            if (doc.data().health_records) {
                healthRecords = doc.data().health_records;
            }

            healthRecords.push(health_records);

            firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(phone).update({ health_records: healthRecords });
            firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(phone).update({ last_interaction_on: last_interaction });

            res.send("User Health Records saved!")
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        res.send("Error: ", err);
    })
```

So the if(!doc.exists) {} part works fine, but the else {} doesn't.

[screenshot of the error from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BLEa.png)

Comment: FYI, the res.send() thing is not the issue as against what's shown in the console. I'm using the same thing everywhere in the code & it works just fine.

Comment: It seems your code is part of a Cloud Function. Can you please add to your question **the entire code** of the Cloud Function? (Use the edit link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your code is part of an [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions) (use of `res.send()`).

Note that you are sending the response before the asynchronous `set()` and `update()` methods are completed (i.e. before the Promises returned by these methods resolve).

You need to adapt you code as follows:

```
let updateType = "Added";
firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(phone).get()
    .then(doc => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
            console.log("Adding new Record");
            var user = {
                phone: phone,
                health_records: [],
                last_interaction_on: last_interaction
            };
            user.health_records.push(health_records);

            return firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.phone).set(user);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Updating Records");
            var healthRecords = [];
            if (doc.data().health_records) {
                healthRecords = doc.data().health_records;
            }

            healthRecords.push(health_records);

            updateType = "Updated";
            return firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(phone).update({ health_records: healthRecords, last_interaction_on: last_interaction });
        }
    })
    .then(() => {
        res.status(200).send(updateType);  //To be potentially adapted
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send(err);
    });
```